# Error INS-35180 when installing Oracle Database 19c in Windows docker container

Tags: windows, oracle, docker

I'm currently trying to install Oracle Database 19c interactively in a Windows docker container and I keep getting the same error message.

My Host runs Windows Server 2019 Standard and I'm using Docker version 20.10.9, build 591094d.
If sourced the Oracle installation files for Orcale Database 19c Version 19.3 from the official website:
https://www.oracle.com/de/database/technologies/oracle19c-windows-downloads.html

The image I'm using is based on the official Windows Server 2019 image by Microsoft.

I've been following the instructions in this presentation:
https://www.oracle.com/docs/tech/oow19-dockerforwindows.pdf

I'm aware that Oracle Database 19.7 fixes some issues with Windows docker containers but I can't find a download link for that and the presentation descirbes workarounds for those issues, which I followed.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Base image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

# copy golden db image after taking it from OTN
COPY WINDOWS.X64_193000_db_home.zip c:/data/db_home.zip

# unzip Oracle golden db image and install VS2013 runtime
RUN powershell -command Expand-Archive c:\\data\\db_home.zip -DestinationPath c:\\data\\db_home
RUN setx path ".;c:\data\db_home\Bin;%path%;"

ENV ORACLE_HOME c:\\data\\db_home
COPY vcredist_x64.exe c:/vcredist_x64.exe

# Install VS2013 runtime env
RUN powershell.exe -Command \
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; \
Start-Process c:\vcredist_x64.exe -ArgumentList '/install /passive /norestart ' -Wait ; \
Remove-Item c:\vcredist_x64.exe –Force

# Provide response file to install Oracle Software Only (modified to workaround bug)
COPY db.rsp c:\\data\\db.rsp

#Execute response file to install Oracle Software Only
RUN c:\data\db_home\setup.bat -silent -responseFile c:\data\db.rsp
```

I use a customized response file With (INVENTORY_LOCATION fix added) and can provide details if necessary.

Building the docker container the Oracle installer (setup.bat) then gives me the following output:

```
Setupassistent von Oracle Database wird gestartet...
[WARNING] [INS-13001] Oracle-Datenbank wird auf diesem Betriebssystem nicht unterstützt. Die   Voraussetzungsprüfungen werden nicht auf dem System durchgeführt.
   URSACHE: Möglicherweise war dieses Betriebssystem zum Zeitpunkt des Release dieser Software nicht in der Zertifizierungsliste enthalten.
   AKTION: Im My Oracle Support-Portal finden Sie die aktuellsten Zertifizierungsinformationen für dieses Betriebssystem. Setzen Sie die Installation fort, wenn das Betriebssystem nach dem Release dieser Software zertifiziert
wurde.
[FATAL] [INS-35180] Prüfung auf verfügbaren Speicher nicht möglich.
*ZUSÄTZLICHE INFORMATIONEN:*
Exception details
 - PRVG-1901 : Verzeichnis "C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\InstallActions2024-02-06_11-31-17AM\CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ContainerAdministrator\" für CVU-Remote-Ausführungsframework konnte auf Knoten "93e1bbb9fbe4" ni
cht eingerichtet werden Wählen Sie einen anderen Arbeitsbereich für das Framework 93e1bbb9fbe4 : PRKN-1014 : Remote-Befehl "C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\InstallActions2024-02-06_11-31-17AM\CVU_19.0.0.0.0_
ContainerAdministrator\\exectask.exe" konnte nicht auf Knoten "93e1bbb9fbe4" ausgeführt werden.Failed during connecting to service 93e1bbb9fbe4 : Failed during connecting to service Version von exectask konnte von Knoten "93e1bbb9fbe4" nicht abgerufen werden


Installationssessionlogs wurden verschoben in:
 C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\InstallActions2024-02-06_11-31-17AM
```

If I look at the .out file in C:\Program Files\Oracle\Inventory\logs\InstallActions2024-02-06_11-31-17AM  this is where things seem to start to go wrong:

```
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [RemoteExecCommand.executeInternal:1261]  executing the command: 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\InstallActions2024-02-06_10-55-17AM\CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ContainerAdministrator\\exectask.exe' with args '-getver ', 'm_stdin == null ->true', 'm_localExecution ->true', 'm_chkException ->false'
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [Utils.getLocalHost:487]  Hostname retrieved: 93e1bbb9fbe4, returned: 93e1bbb9fbe4
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [WindowsSystem.dorunRemoteExecCmd:3118]  _WS_: Calling windowsNative with cmd: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\InstallActions2024-02-06_10-55-17AM\CVU_19.0.0.0.0_Co
ntainerAdministrator\\exectask.exe
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  sprvmjni: isCopy=1 cmd=C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\InstallActions2024-02-06_10-55-17AM\CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ContainerAdministrato
r\\exectask.exe

[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  sprvmjni: isCopy=1 node=93e1bbb9fbe4

[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  num args: 1

[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  args[0] = -getver

[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Trying to open a named pipe
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  About to open pipe
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  calling create file for pipe \\93e1bbb9fbe4\pipe\srvmremotexecpipev2
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  None-pipe-busy error 1231
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  sprvcli: retval = 7

[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [nativesystem.WindowsNative.Native]  Couldn't talk to service
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [WindowsSystem.dorunRemoteExecCmd:3122]  _WS_: WinNative returned: false
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [RemoteExecCommand.executeInternal:1292]  cmdSuccess status: false
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [RemoteExecCommand.execute:1050]  Second attempt to run the command 'C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\InstallActions2024-02-06_10-55-17AM\CVU_19.0.0.0.0_ContainerAdministrator\\exectask.exe'  status: false
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [RemoteExecCommand.execute:1062]  cmdSuccess status: false
[Worker 1] [ 2024-02-06 10:55:59.884 MEZ ] [VerificationCommand.execute:419]  commandResult.getErrorString()=PRKN-1014 : Remote-Befehl "C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\InstallActions2024-02-06_10-55-17AM\CVU
_19.0.0.0.0_ContainerAdministrator\\exectask.exe" konnte nicht auf Knoten "93e1bbb9fbe4" ausgeführt werden.Failed during connecting to service
```

So there seems to be a problem with opening a connection to a named pipe. But I have no idea how to work around that.

I'm also quite constraint in the environment I have to work with, so switching to Linux is not an option.
Did I overlook anything I need to configure? Is there any way to get past this issue?
I'm happy to provide more detailed Information if needed.

I've tried to run the installer as different users (Local admin/Local user) with no avail.
I'm at a bit of a loss here since I'm quite new with docker and Oracle Database and if I search for help I only find information about two of the three topics Windows,Oracle DB, Docker at the same time.

Thanks for your help!